# JVM optimization with JProfiler

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jprofiler

I am measuring functionality in an application that the client said was to slow.
I am using JProfiler with IntelliJ integration.
See the analysis below:

I am wondering on which factors should i focus?

See: https://jsfiddle.net/mxyw5bnu/

Can someone see something interesting here?

I did not post this `html` as a snippet cause the browser hangs while doing it.

Comment: `pl.a.sc.x.back.comm.process.AsyncProcessTask.execute(java.util.Optional)` seems to take 3.8 seconds. Without a breakdown of timings of that method in a call stack, it's hard to say why it takes so long - but it does take a very long time. Is that expected?

Comment: if i am right then operations below can be in the same time frame as this task, for example: `pl.a.sc.x.back.pol.importer.property.bo.polimport.ImportNonStandardPropertyPolService.importPolData(pl.a.sc.x.back.pol.bo.service.bancassurance.polimportOperationRequest)`
is that correct?

The time suggest so (cause only 1 invocation and the whole function did not take more than 15 seconds). So it's `call stack` right? I think that the method can take some time - but on which factor on it I can focus to optimize it.

Comment: Also i saw `zipkin` that it took 72 seconds (many threads probably, 100 invocation) - i will try to change it from 100% to 10% and see if that changes.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you need to read [the manual](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf). All of it. Don't skip sections. Don't assume you know things. Don't just blindly click the API. You obviosuly have no idea how to interpret the results, there's nothing the open source community can do to help you. The other option is to hire a consultant, have them sign and NDA, and give them access to the source. Sorry to be blunt.

Comment: i started recrording before action, then stopped - so from this result someone should know which is the main factor of taking time in my app and on which factor i can focus. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look into `pl.a.sc.x.back.pol.bo.assembler.polversion.PolVersionDtoAssembler.toDto()` - only 2 invocations took over a second which might be too much for supposedly POJO conversion. 
Also, have a look into methods which have a large **Outlier Coefficient** that shows how strongly the slowest invocation deviates from the median time